# Explicitly add a disabled option to choice field

Tags: symfony

here is my form type class:

```
  use App\Entity\User;
use App\Entity\UserSubscriptionTier;
use App\Security\UserProvider;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;

class FeedFilterType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @var UserProvider
     */
    protected $userProvider;

    /**
     * @var UserRepository $userRepository
     */
    protected $userRepository;

    public function __construct(UserProvider $userProvider, UserRepository $userRepository)
    {
        $this->userProvider = $userProvider;
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('creators', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices'  => $this->userRepository->getCreatorsSubscribedToByUser($this->userProvider->getCurrentUser()),
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'required' => false,
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => false,
                'attr'=> array('class'=>'custom-select'),
                'choice_value' => function (User $entity = null) {
                    return $entity ? $entity->getId() : '';
                },
                'placeholder' => 'Subscriptions' /* This didn't work */ 
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array());
    }
}
```

What I want to do is, manually insert a disabled option as the first option in my select, so it appears as a heading, for example:

[image]
How can I tell Symfony forms that before all the entity options, I want to insert a disabled option, as a header?

Setting the `'placeholder' => 'Subscriptions'` did not work.

I also tried using sub-arrays like:

```
               'choices' => array(
                'Subscriptions' => $this->userRepository->getCreatorsSubscribedToByUser($this->userProvider->getCurrentUser()),
                ),
```

But the "Subscriptions" came out in italics and bold, and that won't be ok with my front-end guy as it is out of line with the rest of the CSS.

Comment: You mean a placeholder ?

Comment: I just added this in the form type class and it didn't work:  'placeholder' => 'Subscriptions'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to create `<optgroup>` in HTML. There are two ways to achieve that in Symfony.

One way would be to prepare [adequate `choices` array structure](https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/reference/forms/types/choice.html#grouping-options) like:

```
'choices' => [
    'Subscriptions' => [
         1 => 'magik',
         // other subscribtions
    ]
],
```

But you use repository to get choices, so better for you would be to use [`group_by` option](https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/reference/forms/types/choice.html#group-by).

The easiest solution would be:

```
'group_by' => function($choiceValue, $key, $value) {
    return 'Subscriptions';
},
```

You mentioned only one group so you should just always return same value.
If you want to have more groups, it should return desired value depending on given parameters.

Comment: Hi Jakub, I tried that but I got this as an error:  The option "choices" with value Closure is expected to be of type "null" or "array" or "\Traversable", but is of type "Closure".

Comment: I had a typo. It should be `group_by` instead of `choices`.

Comment: Hi Jakub, thank you, that worked, but the "Subscriptions" comes out in italics which won't be ok with my front-end guy as it will be out of line with the rest of the CSS.  Can you set the css of the actual option value?

Comment: First I wrote that you can style `<optgroup>` label, but then I realized that in general it's hard to style `<select>` as it's rendered differently by browsers or even same browser but under different OS, so it would be difficult to achieve consistent result across all browsers.

Comment: Ok well thank you for your response, it's the closest one yet.

Answer (score 0):

add this fuction in your formType:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\View\ChoiceView;

public function finishView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    $newChoice = new ChoiceView(array(), 'add', 'Add New disabled', array('disabled' => 'disabled')); // <- new option
    $view->children['creators']->vars['choices'][1] = $newChoice;
}
```

Comment: Hi Hous, I get the following error:   Compile Error: Declaration of App\Form\FeedFilterType::finishView(Symfony\Component\Form\FormView $view, App\Form\FormInterface $form, array $options) must be compatible with Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType::finishView(Symfony\Component\Form\FormView $view, Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface $form, array $options)

Comment: you shoud add use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\View\ChoiceView;  in the top of class

Comment: Can I show how the formType is now ?, edit your question and put the new code

Comment: Hi Hous, I edited the question and put in the new code.

Comment: I can't clear the cache because it gives that error:  Compile Error: Declaration of App\Form\FeedFilterType::finishView(Symfony\Component\Form\FormView $view, App\Form\FormInterface $form, array $options) must be compatible with Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType::finishView(Symfony\C
  omponent\Form\FormView $view, Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface $form, array $options)

Comment: remove the cache folder manually, or cut the fucnction and clear the cache than paste it again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186657/discussion-between-brent-heigold-and-hous).